# C# regular expression with \w and german special characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to capture some text with \w, but this text can contain german Umlaute (Ü Ä Ö), which causes my regex to fail. How can I extend the regular expression to match these cases?

The regex:

```
Regex PFileRegex = new Regex("printfile ps *\\t*= *\\t*\"[\\w\\s]*.ps\\s*\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 Match PFilematch = PFileRegex.Match("printfile ps = EXAMPLE Ä.ps"); //false
 Match PFilematch = PFileRegex.Match("printfile ps = EXAMPLE.ps"); //true
```

I know I can simply add Ü Ö Ä to [\w\s]*, but that is not really extensible.

Comment: have a look at Character Classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AvinashRaj The Double quote was in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, `\w` will match accented letters by default ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)). It looks like you made a mistake elsewhere, but as your code in the question is not syntactically valid, I don't exactly know where.

Here's the same code that I just cleaned up, it should work:

```
var fileRegex = new Regex(@"printfile ps\s*=\s*""[\w\s]*\.ps\s*""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var fileMatch1 = fileRegex.Match("printfile ps = \"EXAMPLE Ä.ps\"");
var fileMatch2 = fileRegex.Match("printfile ps = \"EXAMPLE.ps\"");
```

The unescaped regex is `printfile ps\s*=\s*"[\w\s]*\.ps\s*"`.

Comment: Lukas, I corrected the mistake - I copied the names from the source, where they are quoted too and accidentally added doublequotes^2...

Your cleaned solution works, I honestly don't see why my code did not capture umlaute before.